# Storing pattern in file in a vector effectively

Tags: c++, iterator

Currently, I have this for getting data from a file:

```
ifstream ifs("input");
istream_iterator<string> begin(ifs),end;

vector<string> students(begin,end);
```

But now the data in the file has a pattern:

> `string string int`...

I tried this

```
ifstream ifs(input);
istream_iterator<string, string, int> begin(ifs), end;

vector<string, string, int> students(begin, end);
```

But it doesn't work.

Is it even possible to do it this way or do I have to use the standard for loop?

Comment: Is it just *string, string, int, string, string, int, ...* repeated over and over?

Comment: You should be using class `Student` by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a struct with two strings and an int, along with an overloaded `operator>>`.

```
struct Thingy
{
    std::string a, b;
    int c;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Thingy& t) {
    return is >> t.a >> t.b >> t.c;
}
```

Then you can create a vector of those objects like so:

```
ifstream ifs("input");
istream_iterator<Thingy> begin(ifs),end;

vector<Thingy> students(begin,end);
```